# How to trigger multiple calls using dispatch function in ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

I m using NGRX to dispatch the id's from the array but i need to make multiple calls at once not looping then on ngOninit

below is the code for dispatch:

```js
loadEmloyeePricing(): void {
  let id = [];
  this.cartItem.forEach(a => {
    id.push(a.service.parameters.item_number)

  })
  // id -> list of array ids
  this.site$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((site: number | null): void => {
    if (site) {
      this.store.dispatch(
        LOAD_EMPLOYEE_PRICING({
          payload: {
            pathParams: [site.toString(), id],
          },
        })
      );
    }
  });
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.loadEmloyeePricing();
}
```

Above in the code i need to pass the ids which is in array to dispatch function to make a single call
in payload currently passing single id and looping the dispatch function which i dnt want.

i never done this please provide me some idea or solutions how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to dispatch multiple actions in NgRx (unless, as you do, dispatch them "one by one").

But it's really not the recommended way of doing this, instead consider this:

Dispatch a single action, called (just an example) LOAD_MULTIPLE_EMPLOYEE_PRICINGS that takes in an array of the ids to load.

Comment: Dispatch a single action, called (just an example) LOAD_MULTIPLE_EMPLOYEE_PRICINGS that takes in an array of the ids to load. 

you mean that need to pass the ids in comma separated values? 

but in api it holds only single id not multiple thats why i need to combine it to array and call dispatch function once

Comment: There's no requirement to do a one-to-one mapping between your payload and HTTP-interactions.

Instead, consider having your NgRx Effect iterate through the payload and do the HTTP interactions

Comment: so there is no way to trigger multiple apis at one time?

Comment: Sure, use the RxJs `merge`-operator (https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/merge), eg.: `merge(this.http.get(...), this.http.get(...), ...)`

Comment: but again this will be normal http call without using dispatch effect method

Comment: I think I need to see more of your code, it's quite difficult to help you without seeing the part where you're doing the http call.

Normally, you'd use a @ngrx/effect to translate the dispatched action to one (or more) HTTP calls, that would be the place where you exchange the action (having multiple ids) for one or (in. your case) multiple HTTP calls.